# Save image to MySQL with SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, file-upload

I don't know how to save an image into my DB and I tried with this code, but not workin:
Form is:

```
<form
    method="post"
    role="form"
    th:object="${newPainting}"
    th:action="@{/admin/add-new-painting}"
    th:csrf="${_csrf.token}"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
                
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="img" class="form-label">Immagine quadro</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="file" id="img" name="img">
        <p th:errors="*{img}" class="text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('img')}"></p>
    </div>      
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary"type="submit">Aggiungi</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller is:

```
@PostMapping("/add-new-painting")
public String createPainting(@ModelAttribute("newPainting") @Valid Painting painting,
                             @RequestParam("img") MultipartFile imageFile,
                             BindingResult bindingResult) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "admin/add-new-painting";
    }
        
    try {
        byte[] imageData = imageFile.getBytes();
        painting.setImg(imageData);
        service.savePainting(painting);
            
        return "redirect:/admin/dashboard";
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        
        return "Errore nel caricamento dell'immagine";
    }       
}
```

Entity attribute:

```
@Column(name = "img", columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
@Lob
private byte[] img;
```

I don't know where is the error and what's wrong with my code. Someone can help me? Thanks

Comment: More information needs to be provided. What error are you getting? Does the data reach the spring controller?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: From your post, I can see that you are converting the image to byte[] and storing it directly in the database. This is not the right way of storing images because byte[] means an array of characters. So it will take time to fetch from the DB. 
The traditional approach is to store it on a third-party storage service ( AWS, Azure, GCP, etc) and store the image link ( reference ) in your DB. If you don't want to use third-party services then you can also store the images where your JAR is running and serve the image through the WebMvcConfigurer class.